# Chrome cancels request on link clicking befoe the page totally loaded. And FF doesn't

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, dom, webpage-rendering

There is a front-end problem in my web-app:
for example I have a page with plenty of JS code executed on that page. There is a link on it like

```
<a href="OneAction.action?nextAction=/further/OneMore.action?param=111"> Examle Link </a>
```

I want to click on this link before page is loaded completely and actually I can do it in FireFox. Current page stops to loading and browser redirects me to clicked link.
But in Chrome nothing happens and I have to wait until the page will be fully loaded. In other case I see in DevTools that this request got "status=cancelled"
How can I change Chrome to treat my links in other way?
Chrome users don't want to wait till page is loaded if they want to go further clicking the link...

I had read about prerendering and similar stuff but still have no ideas how to resolve it...

I would appreciate for any hints.

Comment: If the browser is auto-cancelling the request, there isn't much to do, except making your site load faster.

Comment: @Kroltan, thx for comment. Web-app is deployed on jboss on my local PC. I thought it would be enough fast especially for TCP/IP requests to localhost :) besides FF works properly for me so I thought there is a way to tell Chrome works the same way with links ...not to wait till the full page is loaded

Comment: I've rarely used Chrome, though (only for testing, then quickly ran back to the cozyness of FF), and I'm not sure of this behaviour. But there's a high chance this is not configurable from HTML/CSS/JS, only from the end user interface itself.